# SSL not working on Laravel App only the first page is loaded with https

Tags: laravel, apache, ssl, ubuntu-16.04

I created a laravel app and now i need to run on https.The problem is that on http it works perfect but when i try to type url with https only the first page is loaded.For example about page show error

Not Found
The requested URL /about was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at domainname Port 443

I try many thing on the web to solve the problem but i didn't find anything yet.Do you have any idea.

The Server is running Ubuntu 16.04
Laravel is 5+

Comment: you should check your .htaccess file make sure its complete

Comment: ok just solved the server administrator forgot to put AllowOverride on conf file so now it's working!Thanks for the answer!